# How can I do Java/Kotlin to CLI?

Tags: java, kotlin, command-line-interface

I have a Java/Kotlin program, which gets arguments from `String[] args`, and I need to make it executable from everywhere from console, without prefixing it with `java` word. Like only the name of the program and its arguments. How can I do it?
Like git or heroku:

`name command`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on your operating system, but on Unix the following script would work:

```
#!/bin/sh
MYSELF=`which "$0" 2>/dev/null`
[ $? -gt 0 -a -f "$0" ] && MYSELF="./$0"
java=java
if test -n "$JAVA_HOME"; then
    java="$JAVA_HOME/bin/java"
fi
exec "$java" $java_args -jar ${MYSELF}.jar "$@"
exit 1
```

You need to append this script at the start of your jar using cat, like the following

```
cat script.sh my.jar > my-program
```

And move my-program to some dir in your $PATH. After that, you'll be able to call my-program as usual program.